# Ajax result differs between development and production server

Tags: php, ajax

I have a small ajax script that gets some json data and fills some form fields when the user makes a selection.

I noticed this morning that there was an error when I ran the ajax on my development server but when run production side it worked.  I am assuming this is due to some difference in error reporting between the servers but I can't figure out why.

Dev PHP version: 5.3.13
Prod PHP version: 5.3.16

I have tracked the error to some variables that were only setting if additional rows cam out of the database.  I am retrieving between 1 and 3 rows.

The first row is assigned to $array1 and additional rows go into their own array as $sec_row[0] and $sec_row[1].

```
$array1 = ('Name'=>'George','Address'=>'52 Smith St',....etc);
$sec_row[0] = ('Alias1'=>'Jorge','Location'=>'SimCity',....etc);

echo json_encode(array('result1'=>$array1,'result2'=>$sec_row[0],'result3'=>$sec_row[1]);
```

Note $sec_row is only set when additional results are found.

On the live site when $sec_row is undefined the ajax returns result2 and result3 as NULL.  But on the development server on my localhost it gives me an "undefined index" (if only $sec_row[0] is set) or "undefined variable" (if neither $sec_row are set) error.

I have fixed the error locally by setting $sec_row manually before encoding the json but I don't understand why I needed to do this locally but not on the production server.

Any suggestions as to what setting might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you probably have `display_errors` turned on so it will generate the undefined index error in the middle of the JSON making it invalid JSON which can not be parsed on the JS side.

Easiest thing to do other than fix the error is to turn error_reporting off. But you should fix the error, by checking if the indexes are set and then outputting the value, or `null`.

```
json_encode(array(
  'result1'=>$array1,
  'result2'=>isset($sec_row[0]) ? $sec_row[0] : null,
  'result3'=> isset($sec_row[1]) ? $sec_row[1] : null
);
```

Comment: Ah yes of course!  And thanks for the suggested code.  Very elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would try to correct the error instead of simply ignoring it... Try to do something like this:

```php
$result = array('result1' => $array1);
if (isset($sec_row[0]))
    $result['result2'] = $sec_row[0];
if (isset($sec_row[1]))
    $result['result3'] = $sec_row[1];
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

its to do with the error_reporting levels on your servers
so either turn them off - add the following to the top of the script, or directly in the php.ini if you have access to it - look for display_errors, set to 0

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

or why not build your json_encode beforehand
ie
assuming you always only have 1 $result1

```
for($x = 0; $x <= count($sec_row); $x++) {
    $more_json .= "'result'".$x+2 ."=> ".$sec_row[$x]."," 
}
# strip the last comma off
$more_json = rtrim($more_json ,',');
echo json_encode(array('result1'=>$array1, $more_json);
```

I have not tested this, so the syntax may not be 100%, but you get the idea